# Typescript: Required value in extending string literal union type

Tags: typescript

(Currently using Typescript 4.3)
Suppose I have the following union type defined along with some generic function

```
types.ts

export type Foo = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'

export function Function<F extends Foo>() { ... }
```

What I would like to do is somehow make it so that any generic use of Function should always include type 'a' (i.e. whatever F that extends Foo must include 'a')

In code, what I would like have is:

```
Function<'a' | 'b'>() // succeeds
Function<'c'>() // fails
Function<'a'>() // succeeds
```

Is there any way I can modify the type definition of either Foo or Function to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, type parameters which are declared but unused are [indicative of a problem](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--).  Additionally, there is already a global object named `Function` that you probably don't want to shadow.  To have something more amenable to analysis, I will modify your example to this:

```
type Foo = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

function func<F extends Foo>(f: F) { return f; } 
// function func<F extends Foo>(f: F): F
```

Here `func()` takes a value of type `F` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Foo`, and returns the same value.  The type signature is therefore `<F extends Foo>(f: F) => F`.

When you call `func()`, you *could* manually specify the type parameter `F`:

```
const x = func<"a" | "b">(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b");
// const x: "a" | "b"
```

but this is rarely better than letting the compiler infer it:

```
const y = func(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b");
// const y: "a" | "b"
```

so from here on out I will just let the compiler infer the type parameter:

---

You're asking to make sure that anything specified for `F` includes `"a"`.  Put another way, you want `F` to have an *upper bound* of `Foo`, and a *lower bound* of `"a"`.

So the following should succeed:

```
func(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b"); // okay
func("a") // okay
```

and the following should fail:

```
func(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "d"); // fails
func("c") // should fail but doesn't
```

Right now `func("c")` fails

---

Unfortunately, there is no syntax in TypeScript to directly support constraining type parameters "from below" this way.  There is a longstanding feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#14520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520) to support this using the `super` syntax ([as in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html)), so that one might say something like `F super "a"` the way one currently says `F extends Foo`, but such a feature is not directly supported.

Luckily, you *can* use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to emulate lower bounds.  For example:

```
function func<F extends ("a" extends F ? Foo : "a")>(f: F) { return f; }
// function func<F extends "a" extends F ? Foo : "a">(f: F): F
```

This might be hard to follow, but it enforces both `F extends Foo` and `"a" extends F` (the latter being another way to say `F super "a"`). And it behaves how you want:

```
func(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b"); // okay
func("a") // okay
func("c") // fails
```

---

Before you adopt such a strategy, however, it might be worthwhile to consider whether or not this is necessary.  You might be able to get away with just an upper bound, if you change your type parameter definition.

Instead of saying that you want a type parameter `F` where `"a" extends F` and `F extends Foo`, you could equivalently say that you want a type parameter `G` where `G extends Foo`, and then define `F` as `G | "a"`.

In particular:

```
function func<G extends Foo>(f: G | "a") { return f; }
// function func<G extends Foo>(f: G | "a"): G | "a"
```

It is now no longer possible for `"a"` not to extend `F`, because `F` is just a name we give to the union of `G` and `"a"`.  Of course, since you are changing the definition of the type parameter, it will change the inference and IntelliSense display accordingly:

```
func(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b"); // okay
// function func3<"b">(f: "a" | "b"): "a" | "b"

func("a") // okay
// function func<"a">(f: "a"): "a"

func(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "d"); // fails

func("c") // okay!
// function func<"c"> (f: "a" | "c"): "a" | "c"
```

That last call does not fail, because the value `"c"` is of the type `"a" | "c"`.  Whether or not it's important for this type of call to fail might influence whether you can go this route.  But for some use cases this might be preferable to an explicit lower bound emulation.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=67&pln=17&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKByAhqqAfNAjLXVAY1QCgyAzAVwDtjgBLOWqG+gHhiggA9gItACYBnWAgB8ACkoAuWAEooAbygAnCMGprWlANxQAvmQD0JtnQbNdlrj36DR4uNLmL5MCsRYjgUXsgWnABE6ME4UMF4wdIAsujAABYAdGrownAAtlJKHFAADMkArFAA-JFhUPJRwQp6pubetL7+1ZW4NV4+fiCB7MRS8Ump6UJZOVB5hSXloeHV0XUNUE0tIG3hHdEU-YMJKWkZ2bkFxWUV85GLBmZQcADW6CBUllJzSrcPTzuvQwej4xO03OcyqkSEtRu5ko6EYABsRC96G9iLUoLcRIk4NQ4UI2LC4VA8NQ-GMICJaKhgD96EwWEFiABGOx8ATCMRvSqsxxibjleCIDYKVweJSqDRaHRsAzGW79Ok2Tjcbnsi72NlOPnOMFzEXuWBIpl7YaHMbHSanGZqhaQ9HmL7PfqMzloz6PR2WZ3BVEfaEExE0qz0-oAZg4AHF1TznHrIx0wmL1JptLoZct5dYGRGo6qBbGIu95HGLoGQ8b-kcJlMzrNKja6na7u705YFQywzU9aCtrUNgXtoay+9Gw6W7TM6GOLqZEKNqXyyNK0Ca9bwba5f7597Xfb3QBCMdBxXEDuoqASKAztUdH19m-BMhAA)